# Updating services for Angular17: Dependency Injection

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, constructor, angular17

I have 2 questions:

1. What is the difference between @Inject() and just inject() in Angular?
2. Leading to my second question, if I am updating a service and it has a constructor that I am getting rid of—like so...

```
constructor(@Optional() @Inject(parameter) private window: Window) {
    ...code...
}
```

Would it change to `private window = inject(Window)` or would it stay `@Inject(parameter) private window: Window`?

Answer (score 0):

1. @Inject is a decorator and inject is a function and I would say it's the new way to do dependency injection.
2. Yes you can get rid of the constructor and write something like:

```js
private readonly httpClient = inject(HttpClient);
private readonly window = inject(Window, { optional: true});
```

Further infos on [inject function](https://angular.io/api/core/inject)